# How to make sum in a single digit?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program to sum a digits, Have a look into this program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int i, j;
    int sum=1;
    cout<<"Enter your sum: "<<endl;
    cin>>i;

    while(i>0){
        j=i%10;
        sum=sum+j;
        i=i/10;

    }
    cout<<"Sum: "<<sum;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

So, as I type into output as `25` it'll give me as an output `7`.

But I want to make it in a single digit of every sum, let's say as I type `147`. It gives me an output `10` but I want `1` as an output.

I know it could be done as:

```
while(i>0){
        j=i%10;
        sum=sum+j;
        i=i/10;

    }
    cout<<"Sum: "<<sum/10;
```

and surely it'll give me an output as `1`.

But as I type a number `185` it gives me an output `1`.. But I want the whole sum of digit.

I want that program into which if i type `185`

Output must suppose to be as

```
1+8+5=14
1+4=5
```

And output must be `5`.. So please help me to resolve this kind of issue.

Comment: you just have to repeat the process, till the result is a single digit. repeat -> you need a(n outer) loop.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; No need to use an outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
while(i>0){
    j=i%10;
    sum=sum+j;
    i=i/10;
    if (i == 0 && sum >= 10) // if all the digits of previous number is processed and sum is not a single digit 
    {
        i = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no nested loop!

Do not forget to initialize `sum` to `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is called a [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root). Interestingly enough, it can be computed by simply determining the remainder when dividing by 9 - whereas 0 is substituted by 9.

```
unsigned digitalRoot(unsigned i)
{
    return 1 + (i-1)%9; // if i%9==0, (i-1)%9==8 and adding 1 yields 9
}
```

`digitalRoot(185)` is `5` since `185 = 9*20 + 5`.

Answer (score 2):

> as I type into output as 25 it'll give me as an output 7.

No, it is actually `8` ([demo](http://ideone.com/3g6r6i)). The problem is that you initialize `sum` to `1` instead of `0`.

As far as making the sum a single digit goes, add another loop to your program:

```
for (;;) { // Loop until the break is reached
    while(i>0){
        j=i%10;
        sum=sum+j;
        i=i/10;
    }
    if (sum < 10) break; // It's single digit
    i = sum;
    sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: @rajivmishra It's up to you. To me, two loops show the intention behind the code in a much cleaner way to a reader, because you essentially write down what the algorithm does if you wanted to run it with a pencil and paper. To me, squeezing two logical loops into a single loop in code is a wrong thing to do, but it is only my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class SingleDigit 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int number = 0, temp = 0, result = 0;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the Number :");
        number = inp.nextInt();
        temp = number;
        while(temp>0)
        {
            result = result + (temp%10);
            temp = temp/10;
            if(result > 9)
                result = (result % 10)+(result / 10);
        }
        System.out.println("Single Digit Number for the Number "+number+" is :" result);
        System.out.println("Thank You KING....");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged as C++